# Error invoque REST service method with various @BeanParam beans - "Unrecognized field"

Tags: java, rest, jboss, jersey

I' have this scenario:

1. Bean class

```
public class BeanRequest {
    @QueryParam("id")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class OtherBeanRequest {
    @QueryParam("descr")
    private String descr;

    public Long getDescr() {
        return descr;
    }
    public void setDescr(String descr) {
        this.descr = descr;
    }
}
```

2. REST Service

```
@PUT
@Path("/update")
public Response update(@Valid @BeanParam BeanRequest request1, @BeanParam OtherBeanRequest request2 ) {
        return Response.ok("OK").build();
}
```

3. Problem

When this method is invoqued from frontend (or GoogleREST tool), only parameters defined in variable "request1" is recognized.
The variable "request2" is ignored with the error "Unrecognized field (package.OtherBeanRequest) 'desc'".

Note 1: The test whit Arquillian work fine!

Note 2: DOC: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2545  denote that is possible make method with various @BeanParam beans.

My application server is Jboss 7.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"Unrecognized field (package.OtherBeanRequest) 'desc'` <- this doesn't match your param name `"descr"`

Comment: Thanks Paul, but it's a typo when writing this post.
I tried with 'descr' and it failed. Thanks.